# Symfony 2 doctrine onUpdate cascade

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony2, Doctrine 1.2 and Doctrine/ORM 2.2 for one of my projects.
I am trying to make one of my entities to cascade one of its foreign keys "onUpdate".
This is pretty clearly not supported by doctrine ORM annotations. However, I really need to have the ability to auto-update this foreign key in both tables.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Cheers!

Comment: Nope.  Not in D2.  Kind of sad.

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/UPGRADE.md - removed in 2.2.  for more information discussing the topic see this thread: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1628 .  ORM's aren't really meant to handle this sort of task - is there a reason why you would be updating a key value so often that you'd want that feature?  seems more like a data migration task

Comment: @JasonRoman I know it's a bad practice, maybe I'll have to rethink my database design. Thank you for your reply!